# Running a cosmwasm smart query - out of gas error

Tags: archway-network, cosmwasm

When I query a smart contract with Smart Wasm Query and the computation is especially convoluted the query will error out with an out of gas error. What is the value of the maximum gas limit applied to smart contract data queries?

Error happens when querying with `archwayd query wasm contract-state smart [address] [query]`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each node has the option to set its own "**query_gas_limit**" value in the **app.toml** file so it depends on the RPC endpoint being used. Queries don't require or use gas, but the network calculates the gas used to prevent DOS attacks. You can find some context here: https://docs.archway.io/developers/cosmwasm-documentation/architecture/querying#external-queries. If you check the wasmd readme file it shows how this value can be added https://github.com/archway-network/wasmd/blob/7b749cae5ad30b1edf8a861b3dd2778268a471b9/x/wasm/README.md?plain=1#L12.